# How do I calculate $\int_{\Gamma }^{}f(z)dz$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Let $\Gamma  $ be a curve, which describes the line of the semi-circle of radius 1, that leads from 1 to -1 in the first quadrant. How do I calculate $\int_{\Gamma }^{}f(z)dz$?

Comment: What is $f$? What is the line? Is the contour a loop? If $f$ is holomorphic, then it should be $0$

Comment: The semi-circle leaves the first quadrant; do you mean the upper half-plane? The ultimate answer depends on $f,$ of course. Remember that $$\int_{\Gamma}f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z = \int_{a}^{b}f(\gamma(t))\gamma^{\prime}(t)\,\mathrm{d}t,$$ where $\gamma\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb{C}$ suitably parametrizes $\Gamma$ ($a$ and $b$ must be suitably chosen). Such parametrizations are *very* standard, so I'll leave it to you to fill in the details.

Comment: [Residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) it sounds like